# Return a value not an array from a controller to view php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use this in my controller,

```
function phpcalview()
{
    $year = $this->input->post('yearvv');
    $year1 = $year+1;
    //echo $year1;
    $this->load->view('phpcal',$year1); 
}
```

How to `$year1` value to my view `phpcal` and get that value in the textbox `yearvv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function phpcalview()
{
    $year = $this->input->post('yearvv');
    $data['year1'] = $year+1;
    $this->load->view('phpcal',$data); 
}
```

in view:

```
echo $year1;
```

Comment: Thanks.. Is this the same way in all MVC based frameworks?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "get that value in the textbox `yearvv`" put this in your view:

```
<input type="text" name="yearvv" value="<?=$year1?>" />
```